# How to correct the GraphicEx InChunk() Function?

Tags: image, delphi, png, delphi-xe3, graphicex

I am trying to port the GraphicEx component library (for PNG files) from my Delphi 2006 to XE3 (Finally got it) when correcting the basic errors, I got stuck in this error:

```
"TPNGGraphic.IsChunk" invalid type cast
```

At lines:

```
function TPNGGraphic.IsChunk(ChunkType: TChunkType): Boolean;

// determines, independant of the cruxial 5ths bits in each "letter", whether the
// current chunk type in the header is the same as the given chunk type

const
  Mask = not $20202020;

begin
  Result := (Cardinal(FHeader.ChunkType) and Mask) = (Cardinal(ChunkType) and Mask); // <-- this line
end;
```

Does anyone know what should I do to correct it?

Comment: Any reason why the built-in PNG component won't serve your needs. You likely don't need GraphicEx any more.

Comment: Looks like the name of the library was chosen very carefully to avoid websearch troubles!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TChunkType is defined as

```
type
  TChunkType = array[0..3] of Char;
```

So the compiler can't cast the `TChunkType` type into a Cardinal.

Try changing the definition to

```
type
  TChunkType = array[0..3] of AnsiChar;
```

Comment: +1 The code is littered with `Char`. Going to need a lot of work.

Comment: Woa... I think it's better to declare it as `array[0..3] of byte` since I doubt the intention is to see that _chunk_ as character data.

Comment: +1. But @jachguate, such chunks usually contain human-readable section names, IOW, what you call "character data" (or text) and not just 4 bytes of binary data. That is why generally `char[4]` is used (in C), and `array [0..3] of AnsiChar` should be used in Delphi.

Comment: @Rudy In fact in C char is **the** type for a byte. There is no distinction, as there is in Delphi, between AnsiChar and Byte.

Comment: It is the type for a byte-sized character, as the name "char" already shows. IOW, the size of char is indeed always one byte. Fact is that in such chunks, you get human-readable names, so AnsiChar is quite correct.